# Forever and ever

Tags: word-usage

Even though I know what "forever and ever" means I would like to know if I can write a love letter to my girlfriend and say something like "I'll love you forever and ever" or even "my name and her name forever and ever" any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use that phrasing, with a couple of reservations.

1) If you really want to make an impression, don't use the contraction **I'll**, especially in writing: it's a bit informal. Write **I will** in full.

2) According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forever%20and%20ever%2Cfor%20ever%20and%20ever&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforever%20and%20ever%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20ever%20and%20ever%3B%2Cc0), in British English, we say exclusively "for ever and ever". In American English, "for ever and ever" is the most common, but "forever and ever" does also occur.

So, I recommend that you write:

> I will love you for ever and ever

Comment: Thank you so much JavaLatte I'll thought I'd make sure because I have heard that phrase in chistian music.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez The proper names of religious faiths and their central figures are always capitalized!

Comment: You mean I should write "Christian Music" instead of "christian music"?

Comment: Yes, that is what PE meant.

Comment: @Jesseיִשַׁי ahem.... Not wanting to be P.E.Dant-ic, but... "Christian Music" is also incorrect, as most people do not consider music to be a religion.  It should be "Christian music".

Comment: @JavaLatte True because, while genres are not capitalized, religions are. Thank you for being the first to show the English learner how it should be written.